# Views: Change path and redirect old to new path?

Tags: views, redirection, path-aliases

I would like to change the path for one of my Views. How do I redirect the old Views path to the new one including all the variables that may follow the old path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://drupal.org/project/redirect for Drupal 7. It provides an administrative interface to manage page redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module to redirect path.

> This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another
>   path or an external URL, using any HTTP redirect status.